# Download apk from market to sdcard programmatically

Tags: android, google-play, apk, sd-card

I would like to **download an .apk file on the market** to the sd-card **without any user interaction** (I mean to do it in background, without launching a browser or the Market Application)?

Is there a special URL to use?

Something like `http://market.android.com/details?id=<your_package_name>` always launch the Market Application, doesn't it?

Comment: i think(not sure) market.android.com not give rights to download apk. it is directly install only.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.
You can, however, download an APK file from an outside source bu using the method suggested above.
This will notify the user via toast something like "Starting Download" and will not install the apk automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `HttpURLConnection`?

```
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(url_str);
        con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream input_stream = con.getInputStream();
        ...
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) { ErrorMSG("Bad URL"); }
    catch (IOException e) { ErrorMSG("Failed to download file from input stream"); }
    finally
    {
        if (con != null) con.disconnect();
    }
```